# c++ when entry not found in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I have a map of pointers. I am looking for an entry and then make a local copy of pointer and delete the entry in the map. My question is in case we could not find an entry, could this code create a problem?

```
std::map<int, object*>::iterator it2 = m_Frames.find(m_num);
m_objpointer = it2->second;
m_Frames.erase (it2);
```

Comment: `if (it2 != m_Frames.end()) // etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's undefined behaviour here, since you dereference iterator. Check on equality to `end`.

```
if (it2 != m_bTTEFrames.end())
{
   // do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I there is no entry it will return the end of the map!.
So it will be an undefined behaviour.
better to do this:

```
if((it2 = m_Frames.find(m_num))!=m_Frames.end())
{
  m_objpointer = it2->second;
  m_Frames.erase (it2);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`it2` pay point to `m_Frames.end()`, dereference it by `it2->second` invokes **undefine behavior**. You need to test the `iterator` if iterator is valid or not:

```
if (it2 != m_Frames.end())  // test if iterator is valid  
{
   //.. do stuff
   m_objpointer = it2->second;
   m_Frames.erase (it2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a problem. If the entry doesn't exits then `end` iterator is returned which must not be dereferenced. You need a check for that case.

Answer (score 1):

*"could this code create a problem?"*

**Yes**. `std::map::find` might return `m_Frames.end()` in this case, which is *past-the-end* element, i.e. you will try to access invalid memory, which will result in *undefined behavior*.

You should check whether the element has been found or not, and if not, then handle such scenario explicitly:

```
if (it2 != m_Frames.end()) {
    m_objpointer = it2->second;
    m_Frames.erase(it2);
}
else {
    // TODO: element not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will be a problem unless you check the returned value from `find`.

```
std::map<int, object*>::iterator it2 = m_Frames.find(m_num);
if (it2 != m_Frames.end()) {
    m_objpointer = it2->second;
    m_Frames.erase (it2);
}
```